# How to get textarea value to controller without form::open

Tags: php, laravel, post, getvalue

Here i want save to database, the value 'isi' from textarea, when i running the function, always get null value from textarea, what i do for fix that ?
thanks.

Here script in view :

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <div class="box-body">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Apa yang Anda pikirkan ?">{!! Input::old('quoteinput') !!}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                <a href="{!! URL::to('/timeline/quote') !!}">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Posting</button>
                </a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Here script from controller :

```
public function postQuote()
    {
        $Qdata = new QuotesModel;
        $Qdata -> kode_user     = Auth::user()->kode_user;
        $Qdata -> kode_quote    = 'Q'.strtotime(Carbon\Carbon::now()).rand(100,999);
        $Qdata -> isi           = Input::get('quoteinput');
        $kategori               = 'quote';

        if($Qdata->save())
        {
            $this->postToTimeline($Qdata->kode_quote , $kategori);
        }

        Session::flash('message', 'Berhasil memposting !');
        return redirect()->back(); 
    }
```

Here script in route:

```
Route::get('/timeline/quote', 'ClientTimeLineContr@postQuote' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get value without creating form in html, wether you do it with `form::open` or by `<form>` tag. You also have to give the name to the `textarea`.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
    <dorm method="GET" action="{!! URL::to('/timeline/quote') !!}">
        <div class="box-body">
            <textarea name="quoteinput" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Apa yang Anda pikirkan ?">{!! Input::old('quoteinput') !!}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Posting</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank for your attention and answer, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to get textarea value without form. And to save it to database use AJAX.

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="quoteinput" class="form-control mytextarea" rows="3" placeholder="Apa yang Anda pikirkan ?">{!! Input::old('quoteinput') !!}</textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Posting</button>
```

**Jquery and ajax:**

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $('textarea.mytextarea').val();   //this is the value of textarea
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{url('/timeline/quote')}}",
        data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "text": text
        },

        success: function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(res == true)
            {
                 alert('saved');            
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function postQuote(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $text=$request->text;
            //save this textarea value to database
            echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
    }
```

Comment: This will be my reference. Thanks

Comment: this worked for me